# How to efficiently sort the records by time before using "context by" in DolphinDB?

Tags: dolphindb

For the following table "t":

```
symbol time         volume
A      09:30:01     10
A      09:30:02     20
B      09:30:02     100
B      09:30:01     200
......
```

I would like to calculate cumulative volume for each stock. Since some stocks are not sorted in ascending order on time, I have to sort before using "context by":

```
t = select * from t order by symbol, time
select symbol, time, cumsum(volume) from t context by symbol
```

I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to conduct the sorting before "context by".

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SQL extension "csort" in DolphinDB.

```
select symbol, time, cumsum(volume) from t context by symbol csort time
```

It will sort the rows within each symbol group before conducting the cumsum calculation.